# Sharepoint API (Refused to connect because it violates the following content security policy...)

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, cors

Good Day,

I am currently having issues connecting my SharePoint API.
There are no problems running the SharePoint API query on the browser.
However, when it comes to the function call this issue arises.
The API call is being processed on the *front end* using vanilla JavaScript only.

I tried adding the following code below to the HTML file, however it did not work.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="connect-src 'self'" />
```

Do I have to add any special request headers or meta tags? Please do let me know.
** I do not have access to the Sharepoint Server and do not have the rights to install external libraries for the current files.**

I am getting the an error:

```
"Refused to connect to "https://test.com/_api/search/query?querytext=%27civil%27" because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive "connect-src 'unsafe-inline' https://test.com wss://test.com https://localhost"
```

This is my implementation of the API call below

```
function sharePointAPITestCall(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://test.com/_api/search/query?querytext=%27civil%27", //Use for testing.
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            // headers: {"info1": sessionId},
            dataType: "json",
            success: async function (response) {
                const results = response.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows;

                for (const result of results) {
                    const extension = result.Cells.find(cell => cell.Key === 'FileExtension').Value;
                    if (extension && extension.toLowerCase() !== 'aspx') {
                        const title = result.Cells.find(cell => cell.Key === 'Title').Value;
                        const url = result.Cells.find(cell => cell.Key === 'Path').Value;
                        let hitHighlightedSummary = result.Cells.find(cell => cell.Key === 'HitHighlightedSummary').Value;
                        try {
                            const xmlContent = await readUrlContents(url);
                            if (xmlContent) {
                                console.log(xmlContent)
                            }
                        } catch (error) {
                            console.error(error);
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                if (xhr.status === 500 || xhr.status === 400) {
                    alert('Data Fetch Failed. Connect with System Administrator.');
                } else {
                    alert('Data Fetch Failed. Try again sometime.');
                }
            }
        });
    }
```